# Getting FLV duration with php

Tags: php, flv, duration

I have an flv file uploaded to a server. I would like to display its duration in the following format "minutes:seconds". Can anybody help me with this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code to grab a frame and generate the image from the video...

```
// get the duration and a random place within that
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i " . $videoPath . " 2>&1";
if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) {
   $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
   $second = rand(1, ($total - 1));
}
exec($cmd);

// get the screenshot
exec("ffmpeg -i " . $videoPath . " -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg " . $imageOutput . " 2>&1");
```

$second variable is random number between 0 and total duration.
and the second exec() is to create a image file from selected frame.

$imageOutput is absolute path location to the generated image. 
eg: /home/ariawan/image-generated.jpg

Comment: ariawan, thank you so much for your help man. I am able to get the image in the folder, but it is empty 0 bytes. this is what i have:

Comment: I m not sure what happend, but the server I was working on was restarted, and everything works fine now. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 7):

There is also a FFMPEG PHP extension ie. `apt-get install php5-ffmpeg` then

```
$movie = new ffmepg_movie("path/to/movie.flv");
$duration_in_seconds = $movie->getDuration();
```

This has worked for me previously. The extension is good for retrieving meta-data and testing if an uploaded file is an FLV, etc.

Comment: then divide by 60 to get the minutes and modulo 60 to get the remaining seconds

Answer (score 3):

I´d use the [`getID3 PHP library`](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/), written in plain old PHP without any dependencies.

It not only gives you the duration of the `.flv` movie in seconds, but converts it to `minute:seconds` format already. Here is a code sample with v. 1.7.9 (latest stable version of `getid3`):

```
<?php

// getId3 library uses deprecated eregi_* functions 
// which generate errors under PHP 5.3 - so I excluded them
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

// just for debugging/sample
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// include the getid3 base class in order to use the lib
require_once('./lib/getid3.php');

// path to your .flv file
$filename = './sample.flv';

$getID3 = new getID3();
$fileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);

// echoes something like 127.8743
print 'Playtime in seconds: ' . $fileInfo['playtime_seconds']; 

print chr(10);

// echoes something like: 2:07
print 'Playtime in minute:seconds format: ' . $fileInfo['playtime_string'];
```

Comment: thanks man. I appreciate your help. But I ended up using the second suggestion. Any idea on how to grab the thumbnail?

Comment: @ciprian how to grab the thumbnail should be a separate question.

Comment: @Pekka Ok ... sorry I just figured that this information should be in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

i am using php and ffmpeg to get duration of the video.

```
    $cmd = "ffmpeg -i " . $videoPath . " 2>&1";
    if (preg_match('/Duration: ((\d+):(\d+):(\d+))/s', `$cmd`, $time)) {
        $total = ($time[2] * 3600) + ($time[3] * 60) + $time[4];
    }
    exec($cmd);
```

print_r() the $time variable to see.
make sure ffmpeg installed on your machine..
hope this will help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I created a variable $videoPath = 'skittles.flv'; and I called the $time variable with print_r (time); The result is Array()

Comment: try ffmpeg -i /path/path/videofile.flv. is it running?

Comment: nope ... the file is in the same directory as php file. I created a wordpress template file. Does that matter?    This is the path that I used $cmd = "ffmpeg -i /wp-tube/wptube/skittles.flv" . $videoPath . " 2>&1";

Comment: if the ffmpeg is running. the code should return the duration. where is the location of your ffmpeg? if it's installed in /usr/bin/ffmpeg then the $cmd should be like this.. $cmd ="/user/bin/ffmpeg -i /wp-tube/wptube/skittles.flv"

Comment: $cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /wp-tube/wptube/skittles.flv" . $videoPath . " 2>&1"; this is what I have. For some reason it s still not working.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you very much! I am getting the duration with print_r ($time[0]); The duration is in this format 00:00:45. How do I only get the minutes and seconds? 00:45

Comment: yaay! cool.. ;) 
you can use substr() to get the 00:45 only.. or $str = explode() with delimiter ':' and display only the $str[1] and $str[2]

Comment: It worked in the end. I had a small issue with my sql query. Thank you very much.